# VPN Client with Public Static IP [Route interface traffic to SIngle IP]

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables, openvpn

I have an internet connection which doesn't provide any public static IP. So was looking for solution to provide Public Static IP to Local Machine - which includes SSH from that IP to the Machine. True Public static IP.

I already have a server with OpenVPN setup, but I can't find any solution for routing an interface traffic to a single IP, including all ports etc.

Below is my idea.

```
Client connects via eth0 to VPN Server
|---------------------------------------|
eth0 ------\                            |
            SERVER(VPN Server) ---- VPN CLIENT (10.0.8.1)
eth1 ------/                           /||\ 
 /||\                                   ||
  ||====================================||
  All traffic of eth1 to VPN client(10.0.8.1)
```

I tried different ways to route traffic but they didn't work. If anyone can provide IP tables rules, that will be really helpful.

In short, I am looking to DIY https://vpnstaticip.com/

Comment: Are you aware that to do this the way you propose you will require a bare minimum of 2 IP addresses, and practically a /30 (ie 4 IP address subnet) IN ADDITION to the normal IP address of the OpenVPN server?   A much cheaper alternative would be to do 1:1 mapping between a real IP and an RFC1918 - eg 10.x.x.x IP.

Comment: Yes, Since server is in cloud, I can get IP's. How to do 1:1 Mapping, 
Since I want to use ssh on port 22 as well as on server too, its getting complicated - otherwise I would have used reverse proxy for every other purpose.

Comment: External SSH could be a problem - you would need to either set the systems you connect to as additional VPN clients and you could then reach them on the internal IP or you would need to use an alternative port.   You can map the external IPs to internal IPs with an iptables rule like iptables -A PREROUTING -i ethX -d real.ip.addr -j DNAT --to-destination INT.IP.ADDR